# Azure PostgreSql , extension postgis

Tags: postgresql, azure, postgis

I try to upoad backup file to azure postrgesql server, but I got an error

```
psql:E:/PostgreSqlBackups/WeatherDb/weatherDb_11_08_2023.sql:26: ERROR:  extension "postgis" is not allow-listed for "azure_pg_admin" users in Azure Database for PostgreSQL
```

In the server parameters I have : postgis.gdal_enabled_drivers ENABLE_ALL

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When I tried to replicate the issue in my environment, I got the same error in my environment:

[image]

To solve the error, I followed below procedure:

Go to server parameter and search for azure extensions, select POSTGIS and save it as mentioned in below image:

[image]

After that I tried to upload backup file into PostgreSQL database using below command:

```
psql -h <serverName>.postgres.database.azure.com -U <serverAdminLoginName> -d <dbName> -f <backupfile path>
```

The file is restored to the PostgreSQL database successfully:

[image]